# Show that the sets ${(A^B)}^C$ and $A^{B\times C}$ have equal cardinality

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A,B,C$ be sets. Show that the sets ${(A^B)}^C$ and $A^{B\times C}$ have equal cardinality by constructing an explicit bijection between the two sets.

So the way it is defined in the book (Terence Tao-Analysis $1$) $A^B$ is the set of all functions such that the domain is $B$ and the range is $A$.

$* A^B$ = {all $f:B \to A$}.

So I think about the ${(A^B)}^C$ as the set of all functions {$g:C \to A^B$} which is the same as the set of all functions with domain $C$ and range as the set of all functions $g$ with domain $B$ and range $A$.

$* A^{B \times C}$ is the set of all functions {all $f: B \times C \to A$}.

If $f \in (A^B)^C$ then $\exists g \in A^B$ such that $f(c) = g$ and $g(b)=a$ for some $b \in B$ and $a \in A$. Hence, I think that $h(c,b) = f(c)(b)$ such that $(c,b) \in B\times C$. So i think, that such function can be $h$. But I don't know if such function even exists and I am not sure if I got the $(A^B)^C$ right?

Comment: [Of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) $h$ exists.

Comment: If you imagine these are positive integers, then obviously $(A^B)^C = A^{B\times C}$. In the general case it's the same (positive integers ARE sets).

Comment: How could you make sure $h$ is a bijection?